# How to disable edittext after click on radio button?

Tags: android, radio-button, android-edittext

Hi i have Two radio button(subject and chapter) and two edittext(SubjectName,ChapterName).
My question is that when i click on subject radio button then chapter edittext will
disable. I don't understand how to do this.
Pls give me some reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this :

in`Radiobutton` `onCheckedChanged()`

```
   @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      if(radio_1.getId()==checkedId)
      {
////for Disable :
    EditText edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editboxtxt);
            edt.setEnabled(false);
            edt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
            edt.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            edt.clearFocus();
////for Enable :
         //EditText edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editboxtxt);
         //edt.setEnabled(true);
         //edt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
         //edt.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
         //edt.requestFocus();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

subject and chapter

```
Privet EditText edt,edt1;
 edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editbox_subject);
edt1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editbox_chapter);

edt.setVisibility(8);
edt1.setVisibility(8);

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

  if(radio_1.getId()==checkedId)
  {
     edt.setVisibility(1);
  }
  else{
    edt1.setVisibility(1);
    }
}
```

you try this one method

Comment: edt.setVisibility(8);
 & edt.setVisibility(1);
 is there any default android option for visibility or after that much second